# no suitable method found for configured finagle in Java code

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I've Java polyglot application which mainly has Java code and uses few Scala libraries as well.

The Scala below code compiles fine.

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Http.Client
import com.twitter.finagle.Http
import com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger

object Main extends App {

  private val loggerFinagle = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("FinagleLogger")

  val client: Client = Http.client
    .configured(Logger(loggerFinagle))
}
```

I write the same code in java as below

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Http;
import com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger;

public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.util.logging.Logger loggerFinagle = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("FinagleLogger");

        Http.client()
               .configured(new Logger(loggerFinagle));
    }
}
```

When I compile the code I get below error -

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/finagle-errors/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/finagle-errors/src/main/java/JavaMain.java:10:1: no suitable method found for configured(com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger)
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Parameterized.<P>configured(P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Parameterized.<P>configured(scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (argument mismatch; com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger cannot be converted to scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.client.StackClient.<P>configured(P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.client.StackClient.<P>configured(scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (argument mismatch; com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger cannot be converted to scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.client.EndpointerStackClient.<P>configured(P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.client.EndpointerStackClient.<P>configured(scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (argument mismatch; com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger cannot be converted to scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>))
[error]     method com.twitter.finagle.Http.Client.<P>configured(scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) P
[error]         (argument mismatch; com.twitter.finagle.param.Logger cannot be converted to scala.Tuple2<P,com.twitter.finagle.Stack.Param<P>>))
[error] Http.client()
[error]                .configured
```

Looks like I've to pass the Tuple but I don't know how.

The project in github is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/finagle-errors).

Below are dependency details of my project -

Scala Version - 2.12.6

Java Version - 1.8.0_151

finagle version - 7.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/com/twitter/finagle/Stack$$Param.html), you need to call the `mk()` method on the param, so something like the following should create the proper tuple:

```
    Http.client()
           .configured(new Logger(loggerFinagle).mk());
```